# My "background.js" code to get the selected chrome tabs url is not working properly in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have looked up many threads and i learned how to get the current url of a focused chrome tab. But the thing is when i refresh my extension it only outputs "chrome://extensions/" and when i click on other tabs it doesnt do anything. Here is my code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true, 'currentWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
var url = tabs[0].url;
console.log(url);
});
```

And my permissions are like this

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The background script runs in a hidden background page. It's like a hidden tab that has its own life cycle: it runs when the extension is loaded, installed, re-enabled, or when resumed in case the background script was declared with `"persistent": false`.

Retrieving the active tab at startup of the background script serves no purpose.

The purpose of the background script is usually to register listeners for `chrome` API events. When such an event is triggered its parameters will often include the tab id which generated the event so you won't even need to retrieve the active tab.

Comment: So you advice me to get the urls on like "popup.js" or "content.js"?

Comment: It depends on what the extension does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are executing the query function only once in your background.js.
Try listening to the onActivated event so you get information when the user switches tabs.
Here is an example:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true, 'currentWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
        var url = tabs[0].url;
        console.log(url);
    });
});
```

**Edit:**
You don't even need to use query at this point. Since you have access to the tab id you can use the get method.

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function (tab) {
        console.log(tab.url);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes this is what i needed. No one on the other threads about getting urls constantly, mentioned "onActivated". Now it works just like i wanted it to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you happen to know a way to listen to change of the url on a tab? Becuase yes this is the answer to my question but it just gets the url when the tab changes. Thanks

Comment: @YKerem try using the onUpdated event: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated

Comment: I used on updated event like this: 'chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    console.log(changeInfo.url);
 }); ' It logs the correct url but after that it logs out undefined 5 times . Do you have any idea why that might happen?

Comment: an tab update can have different loading status types. "unloaded", "loading", or "complete". Check `if (tab.status === 'complete')`